# How to Change FTP time out with SSH

Tags: linux, timeout, upload, ftp

I'm trying to upload (transfer) a 35GB file to a linux server through SFTP (filezilla).
After about 15 hours and 8% progress, I got an error on filezilla saying "Connection timed out".

How can I change or disable the ftp timeout?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@3mb's a minute.. wow ( this is going to take some time ) :P

170hours or so... hehe

What is your ftp daemon on the server???

I would attempt to edit these things on your daemon..

http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TimeoutSession.html
http://www.proftpd.org/docs/directives/linked/config_ref_TimeoutNoTransfer.html

And this on your ftp client (Filezilla)

http://forum.hostek.com/showthread.php?230-How-to-disable-FTP-timeout-in-Filezilla

Comment: yeah, its going to take about a week A: proftpd, if you're referring to the ftp server

Comment: Updated my answer :D

Answer (score 0):

Time-outs might indicate the transfer will never complete if your disable timeouts.

Since, so far as I know, FTP and SFTP can't resume an upload, I would do the FTP as a get from the other end, and use resume when the connection times-out.

Since time does not seem to be an issue, if you have the disk space you could use `split` to break the data into smaller chunks, with greater chance of success with the transfer of each chunk.